# How to clear the contents of a csv file from VB

Tags: vb.net, csv

I need to delete/clear all data from an existing csv file from Visual Basic. This seems really simple but I have had a lot of problems making it happen!

Comment: "I have had a lot of problems making it happen" -> Please post your code, or what you tried, and what the result was.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "clear all data"? The easiest option would be to delete the file.

If you want to replace it with an emtpy file, open the file for output, then close it. That should truncate the file.

Comment: Sweet...I got it to work. When you delete a file and create a new one, the new file stays open though. Then when the other part of the code tries to reference it, it is read only. It was as simple as placing a close command after the create file command, but frustrating nonetheless!!!

Comment: @Steve: Good that you got it to work. A note: Please write your solution as an answer, not just as a comment. It is encouraged to answer your own question if you solve it, so others will see your solution.